# MagicalRecord relationship mapping duplicates objects despite primary keys

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, magicalrecord

I'm in need of some assistance for an issue I am experiencing with MagicalRecord data importing. I was under the impression that MagicalRecord was able to handle relationship mapping without duplicating objects by looking at the primary keys (`relatedByAttribute`).

Here's a simple JSON:

```
[
  { 
    parentId: "<unique id>",
    parentName : "<name>",
    children : [
                  {
                     childId: "<unique id>",
                     childName: "<name>"
                  },
                  {
                     childId: "<unique id>",
                     childName: "<name>"
                  }
               ]
  },
  { <another parent with children> }
]
```

I've got an NSManagedObject `Parent` which has a to-many relationship with a `Child` NSManagedObject. The relationship name is `children` and I've set the `relatedByAttribute` on the `Child` and `Parent` to `childId` and `parentId` respectively.

When I parse the JSON the `Parent` is not duplicated and it correctly checks for the primary key and uses the existing object if present. However for the `Children` it duplicates the objects every time I parse the JSON. If I parse the `Children` individually (so JSON just contains an array with children dictionaries) it has no problem correctly mapping the data and using existing objects for `Children` that already exist in the database.

Did I misunderstand and have the wrong expectations for how MagicalRecord maps relationships? Currently I've setup an extension class with 'importChildren:` where I can handle all the look-ups manually and create/import the objects accordingly.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Fogmeister I will provide an answer to what I figured out below. Sorry, I had forgotten about this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to solve this a while back.

What I did was add `relatedByAttribute` in the User Info dictionary for the `children` relationship AND for the `Child` entity as well.

So click on the relationship and set `relatedByAttribute` to `childId` (in my example above) and also click on the Child entity on the left and for this also set `relatedByAttribute` to `childId` in the User Info dictionary for the entity itself.

This allows Magical Record to correctly map using existing objects or create new ones if needed - granted that the ID attribute is 100% unique!

[image]

Comment: it seems to work if you add it to the User Info dictionary of the relationship only.

Comment: @runmad how did you solve it, can you check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066656/magicalrecords-import-data-from-json-nsdictionary-import-relationships

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander Perhaps this answer I posted will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337837/magical-record-import-next-step/16386734#16386734

Comment: Thanks so much, spent a lot of time trying to figure this out!