# Magical Record import with already existing data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm trying to use `Magical Record` to import data into my `CoreData` db.

I'm working on the entity `Person` at the moment.

A `Person` has `firstName`, `lastName`, `personID` attributes. (I know I don't need the idString, I'm not using it internally, it is used to talk back to the server).

Anyway, if I already have the person...

```
firstName - John
lastName - Smith
personID - 1
```

And I download the JSON...

```
[
    {
        firstName: John,
        lastName: Doe,
        id: 1
    },
    {
        firstName: Michael,
        lastName: Caine,
        id: 2
    },
    {
        firstName: Angelina,
        lastName: Jolie,
        id: 3
    }
]
```

I'd want the import to add `Michael` and `Angelina` and to update `John Smith` to `John Doe` because it already exists with the same id vs personID.

I've set the mappedKeyName between id and personID.

Is it possible to do this? I've been reading this blog... http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/ about automatic mapping of key names etc... and wondered if I could exploit this to do what I want?

I have read the part about relatedByAttribute from the blog but I'm not sure where I should be setting it and what to?

Should I set it on the entity Person? Or the attribute personID? And what should I set it to? "id"? Or something else?

Comment: Have a look at [Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4) in the "Core Data Programming Guide", which describes a good technique.

Comment: I'm already using this method thanks. I'm wanting to migrate over to Magical Record to use the "auto import" methods that they have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're using the relatedByAttribute setting in the userInfo area of your Core Data model. You don't mention that in your issue here. I suggest you double check that. And to clarify, it's called relatedByAttribute because the string you put into the value section is the CoreData attribute which relates the entities, no the json (or other object) data. So, check those two things and if there still a problem, please open a ticket on github, preferably with a unit test that helps describe the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did read about the relatedByAttribute but thought it was for data relations. Anyway, I've update my question. Thanks.

Comment: I've read this again and I'm completely lost as to where I should be setting the relatedByAttribute. This isn't a relationship between entities I'm just importing single Person entities from the JSON. Please could you let me know where I need to set the relatedByAttribute and what to? Not sure if I should set it on the entity or attribute and what value to give it. In the blog it only mentions it in the relationship but I don't have one.

Comment: Set it on the entity. I had avoided the word "primaryKey" when setting this up to stay away from the database nomenclature. You can think of the relatedByAttribute as the primary key though.

Comment: I answered a similar question I had myself which I know was of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595815/magicalrecord-relationship-mapping-duplicates-objects-despite-primary-keys/15637764#15637764

Comment: @casademora In that awesome CIMGF post you have about importing, I did find it a bit unclear as to what gets the relatedByAttribute key when initially starting out with Magical Record.

Comment: It goes on the entity to which you are attempting to configure the relatedByAttribute