# MagicalRecord import data for already existing NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, magicalrecord

I found a question like mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544129/magical-record-import-with-already-existing-data), but I don't see any code in the answers.

So the workflow is next:

I create NSManagedObject using next code

```
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"playerID == %@", responseData[@"player"][@"playerID"]];

Player *player = [Player MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate];

// on this line above player attributes are still the same at first time created. the player name is Alex if I po player.firstname in console.  

// on this line below i import new name for player - Greg.
// so I print player.firstname and the console shows me Greg instead of Alex.
// I think it has to update my value but it does't when I try to print our it in the success block.

[player MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject:responseData];

} completion:^{

// here I want to get my players assuming that there is only one Player just for testing.
NSArray *arr = [Player MR_findAll]; // print arr.count = 1 (just test if i work with one and the same entity)

for (Player *p in arr) {
NSLog(@"%@", p.firstname); // type first name and it is Alex, but has to be Greg, because I have print out it after import line and player first name was Greg. But now it's still Alex. What the problem is? 
}

}];
```

The next step I need to update this NSManagedObject using import feature. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [blog post](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/). It explains all the non-code related options to use the import functionality.

Comment: first of all thank that you have time to help me with all my questions, the MagicalRecord is very good thing I seen ever =) Can you check my code I have edited it. Maybe there is another way to work with already imported and existed records, but I make a little workaround that find me record with predicate and then try to modify the object using MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject method. So maybe looks not good, but seems has to be worked. What do you think? I have added comments to each line where I modify or print data of object. Can you see my updated question. Thank you a lot.

Comment: I found my issue the import works good for version 2.0.8 I miss localContext in my code. If I use Player *player = [Player MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:localContext]; everything works good for me...

Comment: Do we need save this question for another people who can have the same question as mine? What do you think?

Comment: also one more question about the predicate, I suppose we can import to data to exist object without predicating?