# Magical Record import (next step)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I've put next step in the title as this is not the same problem as my previous question with almost the exact same title.

I have a `Person` entity.

```
Person
--------
name      - mappedKeyName: FullName
email     - mappedKeyName: EmailAddress
personID  - mappedKeyName: Id
--------
photos
```

And a `Photo` entity.

```
Photo
--------
image
createDate - mappedKeyName: Date
photoID    - mappedKeyName: Id
--------
owner (type Person) - mappedKeyName: UserId - relatedByAttribute: personID
```

There are other objects that relate to `Person` too and the JSON for these comes as so...

```
{
    ObjectId : blah,
    Owner : {
        Id : 12345asdfg,
        FullName : Oliver,
        EmailAddress : oliver@oliver.com
    }
}
```

With this JSON my setup works with the import. Any person records that don't exist (with the Id) are created. And any that do exist are updated.

However, the photos JSON object comes like this...

```
{
    Id : thisIsThePhotoID,
    Date : today,
    UserId : 12345asdfg
}
```

When the objects come down like this the Magical record import stops when it gets to the person import.

The code crashes at...

```
- (id) MR_relatedValueForRelationship:(NSRelationshipDescription *)relationshipInfo
{
    NSString *lookupKey = [self MR_lookupKeyForRelationship:relationshipInfo];
    return lookupKey ? [self valueForKeyPath:lookupKey] : nil;  // it stops here.
}
```

The value of `lookupKey` is @"personID".

Printing out relationshipInfo at the breakpoint gives...

```
$6 = 0x1fd695e0 (<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x1fd695e0>),
    name owner,
    isOptional 0,
    isTransient 0,
    entity Photo,
    renamingIdentifier owner,
    validation predicates (),
    warnings (),
    versionHashModifier (null)
    userInfo {
        mappedKeyName = UserId;
        relatedByAttribute = personID;
    },
    destination entity Person,
    inverseRelationship photos,
    minCount 1,
    maxCount 1,
    isOrdered 0,
    deleteRule 1
```

I really have no idea why this isn't working. I don't get any sensible errors to report.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MagicalRecord cannot map the relationship automatically with this JSON format:

```
{
    Id : thisIsThePhotoID,
    Date : today,
    UserId : 12345asdfg
}
```

In order for MagicalRecord to map the relationship to a `Person` object, it would have to be an object in the JSON as well, for example:

```
{
    Id : thisIsThePhotoID,
    Date : today,
    User : {
        UserId : 12345asdfg
    }
}
```

This way MagicalRecord knows it's an object and it will do the appropriate lookup in your existing database for the `Person` record with the above ID and map the relationship.

So there are two issues with this, though. If you cannot change the JSON output you have to create a category class on `Photo` where you manually map the relationship yourself. I'll get to that after the second issue.

The second issue is that the above JSON format assumes you already have parsed the users and stored the records in your database. If you have not MagicalRecord will create a new `Person` record with the above ID, but since no other attributes exist on that object (notice the UserId key is the only attribute in the dictionary) it will be fairly empty and not include the name and email address. You can always extend your JSON (if you have that possibility) to include those attributes as well in the Person dictionary inside the Photo dictionary:

```
{
    Id : thisIsThePhotoID,
    Date : today,
    User : {
        UserId : 12345asdfg,
        FullName : Oliver,
        EmailAddress : oliver@oliver.com
    }
}
```

The JSON payload is quite small so it doesn't hurt to do that if you can. Plus it will only create a new `Person` record if one doesn't exist in the database already.

And then for the manual mapping. If you cannot change the JSON to the above format you have to manually override the relationship mapping as the JSON is not prepared the way MagicalRecord does mapping.

Create a category class for `Photo` called `Photo+Mapping.h/.m`. I like to stick with `+Mapping` for these. Then the class should be `Photo (Mapping)` in the header and implementation file and you're good to go.

MagicalRecord has a number of instance methods available to override (see the latter part of [this article on MagicalRecord importing](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/) written by the author of MagicalRecord), among them are `import<;attributeName>;:` and `import<;relationshipName>;:`. There are also a `willImport:`, `didImport:` and `shouldImport:` methods on the class itself which allows you to override any mapping.

For your case you can use `import<;relationshipName>;:` or `shouldImport:`. I took these two because one has a bit of a benefit depending on whether you have already mapped all your `Person` objects and they're available for relationship mapping on the `Photo` object.

Here are the examples of what you can do (you can choose to combine a few of them if you wish, it doesn't hurt to do so). A note here: *ALWAYS* use the current `NSManagedObjectContext` when overriding mapping (easily accessible with MagicalRecord through `self.managedObjectContext`) otherwise you will end up with context issues.

Be sure to import Person:

```
#import "Photo+Mapping.h"
#import "Person.h"

// Assuming you only want to import the Photo object if you already have a Person stored this is a great method to tell MagicalRecord whether to continue with importing or not
-(BOOL)shouldImport:(id)data {
    Person *person = [Person findFirstByAttribute:data[@"UserId"] value:@"personID" inContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    if (!person) {
        // no Person object exists so don't import the Photo object - again this is up to you since you might want to create the record if not
        return NO;
    }
    // you can set the relationship here (you might as well) or use the importPerson: method below (doing a second lookup, which is unnecessary at this point)
    [self setPerson:person];
    return YES;
}

// If you use this method you're doing the lookup to check whether a record exist when MagicalRecord is trying to map the Person relationship
-(void)importPerson:(id)data {
    Person *person = [Person findFirstByAttribute:data[@"UserId"] value:@"personID" inContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    if (!person) {
        // if no Person record exists for the associated UserId, you should create one (or not - if you choose not to, it's wise to throw away this Photo object)
        person = [Person createInContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [person setPersonID:data[@"UserId"]];
    }
    // set the relationship
    [self setPerson:person];
}

// finally you can also use the following method when MagicalRecord is done mapping and get rid of the Photo object if the Person relationship is nil:
-(void)didImport:(id)data {
    if (!self.person) {
         [self deleteInContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks very much. You're the first person to say that the import won't work with this format. (My previous three questions have had answers all saying "It first just work"). I'm back to work tomorrow so I'll get to work on implementing your solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @Fogmeister Let me know how it goes and if you have any questions I can help with.

Comment: @Fogmeister I'm curious as to whether it helped you solve the issue?

Comment: Thanks, in the end I asked the back end devs to change the JSON to match the supported format. I haven't tried the other method yet. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Fogmeister OK, cool. Always nice when you can change the API to output the best format for your mapping requirements :)

Comment: I know this answer is kind of old, but it's also simply not true. MagicalRecord *can* import relationships in this format, as pointed out in this article: http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/